# Change Autowired object at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-zookeeper

I have an interface `ClusterHelper` and a class `ZKClusterHelper` implementing that interface. `ZooKeeperConfig` is a class in which we are creating *instance* of zookeeper object. Now, in `ClusterHelperFactory` we have:

```
@Autowired
ConfigAccessor configAccessor

@Bean
ClusterHelper clusterHelper(){

    logger.info("Returning zookeeper cluster herper");
    ZKClusterHelper zch = new ZKClusterHelper();
    zch.setZookeeper((ZooKeeperConfig)configAccessor);
    ch = zch;

    return ch;
}
```

I am autowiring in class B.

```
@Autowired
ClusterHelper ch;
```

Now if I change the value of some fields in `ZooKeeperConfig` class. 
How do I make it to reflect in `ClusterHelper` autowired in class B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you need to do dynamic `autowiring` here. I propose you to create the separate service bean for it and **inject** instead of creating the new one manually.

Take into account that by default **spring** beans have scope `singleton`.

Comment: Hi, I did not got you. For what I should create the service bean ?

Comment: I mean that you don't need to do this `ZKClusterHelper zch = new ZKClusterHelper();` Instead of creating bean through `new` you should create a separate bean for this and inject (use) it.